# Passing both match param and props into react component when using routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional react component and want to render some properties for a selected person in my component.

So I first map a simple list with links to each person

```
      {props.persons.map((person, i) =>{
      return(
     <li key={i}>
      <Link to={`/topics/${person.id}`}>{person.name}</Link>
     </li>
      )
    })}
  </ul>
```

then I make the route

```
<Route path={`/topics/:id`} render={() => <Topic persons={props.persons} />} />
```

as of now I just pass in the persons.

However I also want to be able to pass in the id, so I can find the specific person, and render information about that person. I have tried using the matching property, but that seems to prohibit me from passing in props as well.

Any tips to make a workaround?

Maybe it would be possible to just pass in the properties of the selected person?

EDIT:

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
   const Topic = (props) =>{
  console.log('props are ', props) //logs array of persons
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Topic</h2>
      <p>I have been rendered</p>
    </div>
  )
}




 const Topic = ({match}) =>{
  console.log('match is ', match) //logs match parameter, but now i can't access persons
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Topic</h2>
      <p>I have been rendered</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: sorry I did not get very well what's the issue... if you pass in all the persons, why you can't access their ids through persons directly?

Comment: Because there is no way to know which id is the right one..., because i do not have a match parameter to get the URL parameter

Comment: I can only acces props

Comment: ? `this.props.persons.forEach(p => console.log(p.id))`?

Comment: @quirimmo this would just render all the id's since an array is being passed into the component

Comment: i have made a nedit to the question

Comment: does it make sense now @quirimmo

Comment: ok I think I got what you mean. See one of the answers, that's the right way to do what you are looking for

Comment: Yes exactly @quirimmo. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using the `render` prop on a `<Route>` component, the `render` function is passed an object with the `match`, `location`, and `history` information.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

```
<Route 
  path={`/topics/:id`} 
  render={({match}) => (
    <Topic id={match.params.id} persons={props.persons} />
  )} 
/>
```

Comment: can i know how to achieve this in react-router v6

Comment: @Vinoth sure thing - if you open a new question with details of what problem you're trying to solve :)

Answer (score 1):

You no need to pass id as a prop to Topic component of route so instead to get the id of path param you can do following in the component to get the id

In the Topic component

You can get the id using

```
  props.match.params.id
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route:

> All three render methods will be passed the same three route props
>
> - match
> - location
> - history

So in the render prop for the route, you should be able to reference the match and pass it along:

```
<Route 
  path={`/topics/:id`} 
  render={({match}) => (
    <Topic 
      persons={props.persons} 
      id={match.params.id} 
    />
  )} 
/>
```

This is because the render function is basically a functional component, and the first parameter to a functional component is the props. (However, you don't have to reference the first parameter as `props`, you could use `renderProps`, for example, or restructure it into what you need (`match`) like I did above)

And then in topic:

```
 const Topic = ({id, persons}) =>{
  console.log('id is ', id) //logs id parameter
  console.log('persons is ', persons) //logs persons parameter
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Topic</h2>
      <p>I have been rendered for id {id}</p>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(persons)}</code>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRouteMatch`

So in your example:

```
<Route path={`/topics/:id`} render={() => <Topic persons={props.persons} />} />
```

Becomes:

```
<Route exact path={`/topics/:id`} component={() => <Topic persons={props.persons} />}/>
```

And Topic.js becomes:

```
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom"; // Import this
const Topic = (props) =>{
 
  let match =useRouteMatch('/topics/:id').url.split('/'); // Get url and separate with /
  match=match[match.length-1]; // The id is at the end of link, so access last array index
  console.log('match id is ', match);
  console.log('persons is ', persons);

 return(
   <div>
     <h2>Topic</h2>
     <p>I have been rendered</p>
   </div>
 )
}
```